# SQL Several Count

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, count, conditional-statements

First sorry if my english is bad, it's not my native language.

I have two tables (A and B) with the following columns:

**A:
PRENUMERO (ID), DATA, ARMAZEM, TIPO**

and

**B:
Autoreg (ID), PRENUMERO, PRODUTO**

I want a result like:

*CountA, CountB, CountC, DATE *

CountA is when PRODUTO is equal to 1.

CountB is when PRODUTO is > than 1.

CountC is when PRODUTO has both 1 and > 1 in the same PRENUMERO.

I joined the tables like this:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
> b.[Autoreg],
> a.[PRENUMERO],
> b.[PRENUMERO],
> b.[PRODUTO]
> FROM
> b.[VendasPOS_Linhas]
> JOIN a
> ON b.[PRENUMERO]=a.[PRENUMERO]
> WHERE
> a.[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND
> a.[Armazem] = '111'
> ```

And this is the result:

[image]

So if I do [PRENUMERO] = '1' (for CountA) the result should be for example 1000 and if I do [PRENUMERO] > '1' (for CountB) the result should be for example 1100 and the CountC should be the rest (667). But I do not know how to do it.

As you can see in the line 11 and 12, they have the same PRENUMERO, but the PRODUTO is 1 and the other is 10900... so this is for CountC. If the PRENUMERO is the same (several exactly PRENUMERO) but the PRODUTO is 1 (CountA (like line 8 and 9)) or >1 (CountB) this count only as 1 (DICTINCT here?)

(IF PRODUTO = 1 THEN CountA; IF PRODUTO >1 THEN CountB)

EDIT:

So I did this:

> ```
> SELECT
>     (SELECT
>     COUNT(DISTINCT [B].[PRENUMERO])
> FROM
>     [B]
> JOIN    [A]
> ON    [B].[PRENUMERO] = [A].[PRENUMERO]
> WHERE
>     [A].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND
>     [A].[Armazem] = '454' AND
>     [B].[PRODUTO] > '1') AS X,
>     (SELECT
>     COUNT(DISTINCT [B].[PRENUMERO])
> FROM
>    [B]
> JOIN    [A]
> ON    [B].[PRENUMERO] = [A].[PRENUMERO]
> WHERE
>     [A].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND
>     [A].[Armazem] = '454' AND
>     [B].[PRODUTO] = '1') AS Y,
>     (SELECT COUNT([A].[PRENUMERO]) from A where DATA> '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' and Armazem = '454') AS Total
> ```

And this is the result:

[image]

But I think this is wrong because it's counting the CountC as well.

For example:
If the same PRENUMERO as 1 and >1 it belongs to CountC. What can I do to not count does? (How do I check if PRENUMERO doesn't have 1 and >1 (diferent rows))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
> SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 AND MaxProduto = 1
> THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdCombustivel
>          ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto <> 1 AND MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdLoja
>          ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 and MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdMisto
>          ,COUNT(DISTINCT PRENUMERO) AS Total FROM (
>     SELECT  [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
>             ,MIN([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MinProduto
>             ,MAX([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])            AS MaxProduto
>     FROM    [VendasPOS_Linhas]
>     INNER JOIN [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
>        ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
>     WHERE    UPPER([VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD]) IN ('T','F','C') 
>       AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-11 00:00:00.000' 
>       AND    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '404' 
>     GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] , [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] )Res
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is pretty handy for this, since it's very forgiving of type conversions:

```
SELECT SUM(PRODUTO = 1) AS countA,
    SUM(PRODUTO > 1) AS countB,
    SUM((PRODUTO = 1) AND (PRENUMERO > 1)) AS countC
...
```

MySQL will take the boolean true/false of the `=` and `>` tests, convert them to integer `0` and `1`, and them sum up those integers, giving you your counts.

Comment: And where do I add this? I never did anything like this with MySQL and i'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Well If I understand you are trying to do the next.

- COUNT A -> *Only products=1*
- COUNT B -> *Only products>1*
- COUNT A -> *products=1 AND Prenumero>1*

  SELECT SUM(if(producto)=1,1,0) AS COUNT_A
    ,SUM(if(producto)>1,1,0) AS COUNT_B
    ,SUM((if(producto)=1 AND PRENUMERO>1),1,0) AS COUNT_C
    ,a.DATA
  FROM b
  JOIN a USING(PRENUMERO)
      WHERE a.DATA > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
        AND a.Armazem = '111' AND b.producto>0
  GROUP BY a.DATA;

You are sharing information between count A and count C, for discating this you could use the alias from each tabla to validate by example

```
a.prenumero>1 AND b.prenumero =1
```

but if this is your inner join field always will have the same value for both tables

Regards.

Comment: COUNT A -> Only products=1 
COUNT B -> Only products>1
COUNT A -> products=1 AND Prenumero>1

 
The last one is CountC and it as to have produto = 1 and produto >1 (For example you can see in line 11 and 12 in the image) 

 

The last example you gave :
a.prenumero>1 AND b.prenumero =1
 

I have to check both **produto** and not **prenumero** :S
 

Is there any way I can check if a **PRENUMERO** has both 1 and >1 (different rows like line 11 and 12 in the image) and then count?

Comment: So, should I do a query to show duplicated PRENUMEROS and then check if they have the 1 and >1 for the same PRENUMERO?

Comment: You could do that if prenumero is not a share field. I mean Is not a foreign key and you are not using in an proyection (select) with inner join in the on statement.